# Adding dropped file info to input file

Tags: jquery

I have an image uploader that is drag and drop. Right now it starts the upload as soon as the image is dropped. I am trying to change it to store the file info in an input[type=file] and then it's all processed when the upload button is clicked. HOWEVER, i cannot get the file info to get into the input. HELP?!

Here's what I have:

```
var files=e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
$("input[id=fileholder]").prop("files",files);
```

Why isn't this working? The thumbnails load and everything is correct. I just can't get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody looking for a solution to this problem, I ended up going a different route. Instead of trying to place all dropped files in a hidden input file field, I stored them all in a global variable in javascript. Every time a user drops the file, it is added to the global. Then when the upload button is clicked, the function calls the global and reruns the jquery ajax for each value in the array. I also used this for when the user selects files instead of dropping them.